# How do I prove that $\cos(\frac{1}{2}x)$ is a periodic function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, pi, periodic-functions

Given: $f(x)=\cos(\frac{1}{2}x)$.

Prove: f is a periodic function with period 4π

My math teacher never went over this so I don't know where to start or what to do :/

Comment: Do you mean $\cos(\frac{x}{2})$ or $\cos(\frac{1}{2x})$? I suspect you mean the former, otherwise you might have a problem.

Comment: cos(1/2x) NOT cos (x/2)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: In order for $f$ to be $4\pi$-periodic, it is necessary and sufficient to prove that

$$f(x + 4\pi) = f(x)$$

for any choice of $x$. Use the fact that

$$\cos(x + 2\pi) = \cos(x)$$ for any $x$.

Comment: I am really confused how you prove that.. is there any way you can give a step by step procedure on how to prove this function altogether?